Prove that Cauchy hypersurface is closed
Witten in https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03928 at page#18 proved that Cauchy hypersurface S is closed hypersurface by contradiction. He wrote

suppose that p ∈ M is in the closure of S but not in S. Let γ be any inextendible timelike path  through p. γ meets S at some other point p′, since S is Cauchy. But then, since p is in the closure of
S, it is possible to slightly modify γ only near p to get a timelike path from S to itself, showing that S
is not achronal.

I understood the whole working but my question is it showed that S is not achronal (which shouldn't be so we get a contradiction), but how it proved that S is closed. I don't see any correlation here. Can someone please explain this ? or is there any other(better) way to prove that Cauchy Hypersurface is closed ?

I think this is a "proof by contradiction" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction )

A Cauchy surface is achronal by part of its definition. The strategy of the proof is proving that if it is not topologically closed, then it cannot be achronal. Thus reaching a contradiction with the very definition of Cauchy surface. So it must be topologically closed.
Addendum
I try below to make more explicit the quoted idea of proof. It is a classical proof actually and it can be found in every textbook of Lorentzian geometry.
Definition. A Cauchy surface in a time oriented  smooth spacetime $(M,g)$
is a set $S\subset M$ such that
(1) it is achronal (i.e. it meets at most once any piecewise $C^1$ future oriented timelike curve);
(2) it meets every piecewise $C^1$ future oriented timelike curve that is inextendible (i.e. which does not admit endpoints).
(The piecewise $C^1$ requirement can be equivalently replaced by the smoothness requirement.)
A more precise proof deals as follows, after a formal statement.
Proposition A Cauchy surface is a topological closed set.
Proof.
Take $p$ in the topological closure of $S$ and suppose that $p\not \in S$. I will prove that this hypothesis leads to a contradiction.
Consider an inextendible timelike curve $\gamma$ passing through $p$. Since $S$ is Cauchy, $\gamma$ meets $S$ at $q\in S$, thus necessarily $q\neq p$.
I henceforth assume that $p$ is in the chronological future $I^+(q)$  of $q$ the other case is analogous.
Since $I^+(q)$ is open, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ (which does not contains $q$) such that every point $p'\in U$  can be joined to $q$ with another timelike curve $\gamma'$. Since $p$ is an accumulation point of $S$, there is $p'\in S\cap U$. The timelike curve $\gamma'$ meets $S$ in two distinct points $q$ and $p'$. I proved in this way  that $S$ is not achronal contrarily to the hypothesis that $S$ is a Cauchy surface.
All that means that is $p$ stays in the topological closure of $S$, then $p\in S$. In other words, $S$ is topologically closed. QED
A natural issue is whether or not it is possible to endow a Cauchy surface $S$ with a sufficiently smooth structure, for instance to define tangent vectors to it. In that case it would be possible, in particular,  to distinguish between spacelike, lightlike Cauchy surfaces, etc. For a generic Cauchy surface it is not possible: the only general result, due to Geroch, is that a generic $S$ is only  a $C^0$ embedded submanifold with codimension $1$. In this case no tangent vectors exist. Much more recently Bernal and Sanchez proved a folklore (but not completely established at that time) fact: a smooth ($C^\infty$) spacelike Cauchy surface exists in every spacetime that admits Cauchy surfaces.

Closed here means closed as a set  -- i.e that  it contains its limit points. -- not that that there it has no boundary.

@mike stone Indeed I used the very topological notion of closure. I made more explicit my argument in the addendum.

@ValterMoretti when you say that " p in the topological closure of S and suppose that p does not belong to S " does it mean we are assuming S is an open hypersurface ? (I think I am lacking in some basic topology)

I just assume that $S$ is just a set. “hyper surface” is meaningless in this context  even if Witten maybe wrote it. A Cauchy surface is a set which (a)  is achronal and (b) meets every inextendible timelike curve. That’s all. Later, it is possible to prove that a Cauchy surface is a $C^0$ embedded submanifold with dimensional $n-1$. In this sense it is a hyper surface. But this is proved and it is not part of the definition.

A further improvement is that there are Cauchy surfaces which are smooth embedded submanifolds of the spacetime, in particular spacelike. However that is not the general case.

If a set is not closed it is not necessarily open. Define $S= (0,1]$ in the real line. $0$ belongs to the closure of $S$ and not in $S$, however $S$ is not open nor closed.

I have had a look at that paper. It is not completely rigirously written (though, obviously it is substantially correct). If you want to learn these issues from a rigorous perspective I do not suggest you to use that paper. It is an excellent introduction for theoretical physicists, but the spirit concerns physics and not the mathematical structure underpinning physical notions.

@ValterMoretti can you suggest me some literature that covers these basic things in detail ??

A bridge between theoretical and mathematical physics on these topics is Wald's book on GR. But this part is not treated in detail. A classical book us O'Neill's textbook on semiRiemannian geometry.  The most recent reference is Global lorentzian geometry, second edition by Beem,
